# Why is DataAnnotations <Display(Name:="My Name")> ignored when using a DataGrid with AutoGenerateColumns="True"

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, data-annotations, wpfdatagrid

I'm using the WPF DataGrid to bind to a collection of a custom class.  Using AutoGenerateColumns="True" in the grid XAML, the grid is created and populated just fine, but the headings are the property names, as one would expect.

I tried specifying

```
<Display(Name:="My Name")>
```

from the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace and that has no effect.  I also tried

```
<DisplayName("My Name")>
```

from the System.ComponentModel name space but still the headings are not affected.

Is there no way to specify column headings with the AutoGenerateColumns option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using @Marc's suggestion was the beginning of the solution, but taken on it's own, the AutoGenerated columns still have the property names as headings.

To get the DisplayName, you need to add a routine (in the code behind) to handle the GridAutoGeneratingColumn event:

```
Private Sub OnGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs) Handles Grid.AutoGeneratingColumn
    Dim pd As System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor = e.PropertyDescriptor
    e.Column.Header = pd.DisplayName
End Sub
```

An additional and better solution is to use the ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace and specify ShortName:

```
Public Class modelQ016
    <Display(shortname:="DB Name")>
    Public Property DBNAME As String
    ...
```

OnGeneratingColumn becomes:

```
        Dim pd As System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor = e.PropertyDescriptor
        Dim DisplayAttrib As System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute =
            pd.Attributes(GetType(ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute))
        If Not DisplayAttrib Is Nothing Then
            e.Column.Header = DisplayAttrib.ShortName
        End If
```

Note that the order of attributes in the attribute array changes, so you must use the GetType(...) instead of a numeric parameter...  Such fun!

Answer (score 4):

You might try the older [`System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx). In C# parlance, `[DisplayName("My Name")]`. In particular, this works with `PropertyDescriptor`, which underpins a lot of data-binding.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually tried to say i did what you suggest.  I now fixed the post so it is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

By using @GilShalit post upon, this is what is needed to add in case that you are using Resources (as you probably should for multi culture language support) in C# in this time

**Your property Declaration with Annotation**

```
[Display(ResourceType = typeof (YourStronglyTypedMessagesResource), Name = "YourGridColumnName")]
public string Column1 { get; set; }
```

**Event handler**

```
private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var pd = (PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor;
    var atb = (DisplayAttribute)pd.Attributes[typeof(DisplayAttribute)];
    if (atb != null)
    {
        e.Column.Header = atb.GetName();
    }
}
```