# Hide a Column from a DataGrid when the ItemSource is an Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a `DataGrid` where the `ItemSource` is an Observable Collection bound using `MVVM` archetype. I would like to not show the ID property of the class displayed in my `DataGrid` however I still need the property to exist.

**My Code:**

XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" IsReadOnly="True" Name="dtSearch" />
```

View Model

```
    private ObservableCollection<MyDataClass> myData;
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataClass> MyData
    {
        get { return myData; }
        set
        {
            myData= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyData");
        }
    }
```

Observable Class

```
public partial class MyDataClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an attribute I can give my ID property to hide it from the `DataGrid`?

Do I need to create another class for visible properties?

Comment: is there a visibility property that you can set for the column as a quick way and or shortcut way of doing this based on the OnDataBound event..?

Comment: The issue is that I don't define the column myself, I believe the DataGrid creates them based on the contents of the ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue will happen regardless of whether the data resides in an `ObservableCollection` or not.

To correct this, one must set the grid to **not** auto generate the columns. That is done by setting the property `AutoGenerateColumns=False` and then in the xaml specify the columns desired.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding  MyData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="The Code"
                          Binding="{Binding Code}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="The Name"
                          Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="The Type"
                          Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Check out more column options in the documentation for the [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340710(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 7):

WPF data binding engine binds to all **public** properties of the object. So, the simplest is to make your ID property **internal** (if that doesn't break any other code).
However, there is a more general approach when binding to a list of objects. First, put the following in some common place:

```
public class BindableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ITypedList
{
    string ITypedList.GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors) { return null; }
    PropertyDescriptorCollection ITypedList.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T), PropertyFilter);
    }
    static readonly Attribute[] PropertyFilter = { BrowsableAttribute.Yes };
}
```

and use that class instead of `ObservableCollection<T>`. Then just use `Browsable` attribute to hide members of the item class. For your example it's something like this:

View Model

```
private BindableCollection<MyDataClass> myData;
public BindableCollection<MyDataClass> MyData
{
    get { return myData; }
    set
    {
        myData= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyData");
    }
}
```

Observable Class

```
public partial class MyDataClass
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Changing ID to internal did the trick, however I will decided to do it @OmegaMans's method as provides other benifits such as allowing the name change of fields. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's ok., although I personally prefer controlling most of the aspects from the VM. I would rather use the second approach combined with a `DisplayName` or some `DataAnnotations` attribute as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230402/why-is-dataannotations-displayname-my-name-ignored-when-using-a-datagrid

Answer (score 2):

XAML:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Margin="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Code}" Header="Code"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Type}" Header="Type"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<MyDataClass> data = new ObservableCollection<MyDataClass>();
        data.Add(new MyDataClass { Code = "Code 1", ID = 1, Name = "Name 1", Type = "Type 1" });
        data.Add(new MyDataClass { Code = "Code 2", ID = 2, Name = "Name 2", Type = "Type 2" });
        data.Add(new MyDataClass { Code = "Code 3", ID = 3, Name = "Name 3", Type = "Type 3" });
        data.Add(new MyDataClass { Code = "Code 4", ID = 4, Name = "Name 4", Type = "Type 4" });
        data.Add(new MyDataClass { Code = "Code 5", ID = 5, Name = "Name 5", Type = "Type 5" });

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = data;
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can modify columns in the `AutoGeneratedColumns` event of the DataGrid object.
You can rename them and remove those that you don't want to be displayed.